# jQuery expanding list element

Tags: jquery, html, css, grid

I have a group of `<li>` elements and within them I have the `<div>` with the class `expander`.

When a list item is clicked the expander in the first 3 drops down underneath the list item and this is fine but when you click the 4th option the expander goes on top of it as its on a new line.

The [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LFdfZ/5/) here shows you an example of what my problem is and I hope that someone could be kind enough to help me.

**CSS**

```
section {
    width: 758px;
    float: left;
}
.products {
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
}
.product {
    width: 219px;
    margin: 0 20px 20px 0;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.product a {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 287px;
    border: 2px solid #f2dd09;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
}
.product a .info {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    padding: 10px;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    color: #fff;
    z-index: 6;
    width: 100%;
    -webkit-transition: background 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: background 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: background 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: background 0.3s ease-in-out;
    transition: background 0.3s ease-in-out;
    font-size: 13px;
}
.product .expander {
    position: absolute;
    background: #ddd;
    top: 300px;
    left: 0;
    height: 0;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 10px;
    text-align: left;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

**html**

```
<section>
    <h1 class="page-title">Expander should drop underneath the li element</h1>
    <ul class="products">
        <li class="product-category product first" data-slug="block-1" style="height: 287px;">


            <a href="#" class="">

                <div class="info">
                    <h3>Block 1</h3>
                </div>
                <img src="http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/ThumbnailGridExpandingPreview/images/thumbs/12.jpg" alt="Block 1" width="219" height="283"/>
            </a>

            <div class="expander" style="height: 0px;"></div>
        </li>
        <li class="product-category product" data-slug="other" style="height: 287px;">


            <a href="#" class="">

                <div class="info">
                    <h3>Other</h3>
                </div>
                <img src="http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/ThumbnailGridExpandingPreview/images/thumbs/12.jpg" alt="Other" width="219" height="283"/>
            </a>

            <div class="expander" style="height: 0px;"></div>
        </li>
        <li class="product-category product" data-slug="block-2" style="height: 287px;">


            <a href="#" class="">

                <div class="info">
                    <h3>Block 2</h3>
                </div>
                <img src="http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/ThumbnailGridExpandingPreview/images/thumbs/12.jpg" alt="Block 2" width="219" height="283"/>
            </a>

            <div class="expander" style="height: 0px;"></div>
        </li>
        <li class="product-category product last" data-slug="block-3" style="height: 287px;">


            <a href="#" class="">

                <div class="info">
                    <h3>Block 3</h3>
                </div>
                <img src="http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/ThumbnailGridExpandingPreview/images/thumbs/12.jpg" alt="Block 3" width="219" height="283"/>
            </a>

            <div class="expander" style="height: 0px;"></div>
        </li>

    </ul>


</section>
```

**jQuery**

```
$('body').on('click','.products .product-category', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var slug = $(this).data('slug');
    if ($('.products .product-category[data-slug="'+slug+'"] .expander').height() > 0) {
        console.log('1.1');
        $('.products .product-category a').removeClass('active');
        $('.products .product-category[data-slug="'+slug+'"] .expander').html('').css({'height':'0px'}).parent().animate({height:287},200);
        console.log('1.2');
    } else {
        console.log('2.1');
        $('.products .product-category a').removeClass('active');
        $('.products .product-category[data-slug="'+slug+'"] a').addClass('active');
        $('.products .product-category:not([data-slug="'+slug+'"]) .expander').html('').css({'height':'0px'}).parent().animate({height:287},200, function() {
            $('.products .product-category[data-slug="'+slug+'"] .expander').html('<ul>'+slug+'</ul>').css({'height':'287px'}).parent().animate({height:600},200);
        });
        console.log('2.2');
    }
});
```

Comment: Validate you HTML - Do not wrap divs in links

Comment: @mplungjan 1 forward slash out of place

Comment: you are increasing the height of li to 600px and fixing the expender div 300px from top, it's working fine for top 3 cells but when u click on 4th cell expander still 300px from top that's why it's overlaping 4th cell. So you have to try some another approach for this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed `float: left;` from `.product a`

```
.product a {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 287px;
    border: 2px solid #f2dd09;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}
```

Set `top: auto;` in `.product .expander`

```
.product .expander {
    position: absolute;
    background: #ddd;
    top: auto;
    left: 0;
    height: 0;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 10px;
    text-align: left;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/LFdfZ/6/)